# HashMap in CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, hashmap

We have an existing Spring Boot Security structure which uses CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter with some other filters and database to login users.

The requirement is that each user should not be allowed to login for 30-60 sec once an attempt is made. We are not yet clear if the attempt must be successful or not.

We are thinking of using HashMap to record username (which is unique) with the attempted login timestamp.

If the user is not in the HashMap just add the username in it and go ahead with login. If the user is in HashMap check the timestamp and if this attempt is withing 30-60 sec, just exit from filter. This will not go through login process.

```
private static HashMap<String, DateTime> loginMap = new HashMap<String, DateTime>();
...
...
if(user not in map) {
    put the user
}
else if(user in map and time difference > 30-60sec) {
    change timestamp;
    go ahead to login;
}
else {
    exit without changing time;
}
```

Sometimes the login attempts are 4-5 times for 1 sec. As the HashMap will be accessed by many threads, how stable is this solution? Only first thread will add in HashMap and others will read it.
Is there any other structure or solution we can use?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You can use a thread safe Map like [java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Comment: Thanks @ButiriDan, I am quite new to JAVA so didn't realize that ConcurrentHashMap will work in this situation.